# How to extract an element from within another element using a for loop and inserting into an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to take all the select and input elements within `td` elements inside a table. I tried to first take all the `td`s and place them in an array and then by using a for loop go through each `td` and ask to extract the input/select element in it (all select and input elements have the same class so I said `getElementsByClassName`), and then place the input/select elements in an array that was created outside the for loop. here is the code:

problem is, it only puts the last select/input element inside the `inputAndSelectArray` and I don't understand why.

```js
 var inputAndSelectArray = [];
var tdArray = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(i = 1; i< tdArray.length; i++){
  inputAndSelectArray = tdArray[i].getElementsByClassName("selectAndInputStyle");
}
```

Comment: Try  using i = 0 instead of 1

Comment: Can we see your html?

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to retrieve all your elements at once in a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/NodeList):

```
document.querySelectorAll('td .selectAndInputStyle');
```

[See also](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)